# Using system and echo not providing correct text

Tags: r

I'm using `system()` and `echo` to send a line of text to a `.tex` file, but the text is not correct. This works on my linux station, but not on mac.

**Command**

```
system(paste0('echo "\\bibliographystyle{plain}" >> output.tex'))
```

**Output**

```
ibliographystyle{plain}
```

Comment: Do you really want to use `echo` or other suggestions are also ok?

Comment: @PoGibas Anything that works :)

Comment: Using the wise words of `fortunes::fortune(365)`, you can use `system(paste0('echo "\\\\\\bibliographystyle{plain}" >> output.tex'))`, but I'd go with PoGibas's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `echo`, if you have text already in `R` and want to write them to a file then:

```
tex <- "\\bibliographystyle{plain}"

# Creates new file
writeLines(tex, "file.tex")
# Appends to existing file
write(tex, "file.tex", append = TRUE)
```

Output (on Mac):

> ```
> \bibliographystyle{plain}
> \bibliographystyle{plain}
> ```